# Does the brake pedal always vibrate when ABS kicks in?

Tags: brakes, abs

I’m curious about how ABS and brake pedal vibration works. There are two ways I could imagine it working:

1. When ABS kicks in, it moves the pedal up and down. That physical act is what pumps the brakes. The two things are mechanically linked; no vibration, no ABS.
2. When ABS kicks in, it shakes the pedal and regulates the brakes separately. The pedal shaking is just haptic feedback. You could have a car which had ABS but didn’t shake the pedal.

Which of these two is it?

Comment: Neither. Pedal movement is a side effect.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: #2 and unless someone points out any vehicle that doesn't provide the foot massage feedback when emergency braking with abs activation occurs, all abs brakes give feedback when abs takes over braking as long as the brake pedal is held down while one or more wheels lockup when abs prevents wheel lockup. Here's one description of abs operation; https://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-parts/brakes/brake-types/anti-lock-brake.htm#:~:text=ABS%20Questions,-Should%20I%20pump&text=In%20an%20emergency%20stop%20in,t%20let%20off%20the%20brake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer for definite that the brake pedal on all cars vibrate when the ABS kicks in, since I don't have experience with all cars.

When you press on the brake pedal, the brake master cylinder creates hydraulic pressure that is distributed by a valve block to the brake calipers at each wheel.

If the ABS detects that one of the wheels is about to stop turning when it shouldn't be, the ABS system rapidly opens and closes some of the valves in the valve block to divert some of the hydraulic pressure away from the caliper at the wheel that is about to lock up.

This rapid change in pressure in the hydraulic system is felt at brake pedal as a vibration. So the vibration of the brake pedal is as described in the comments a useful side effect of the ABS operating.  I am sure the car manufacturers could design a brake system that didn't vibrate like this, but then the driver would need some other obvious way of knowing that the ABS had turned on.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! As Chenmunka pointed out, this is not really option (1) or option (2) from my question, although it's more similar to (1). I wasn't thinking through all the possibilities :)

Comment: Something else to think about in conjunction with ABS is Stability Control. These two usually work hand-in-hand, except Stability Control can cause the brakes to actuate with/without pressure on the pedal. This, too, will cause a pulsation at the pedal during activation. I had just such an occasion a couple of weeks back when the truck saved me from going in the ditch during some nasty road conditions.